# Boto3 not really starting an instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm running Python code on an instance and I'm trying to start an EC2 instance using boto3 `start_instances`. The code works and gives the following response:

```
Response: {'StartingInstances': [{'CurrentState': {'Code': 0, 'Name': 'pending'}, 'InstanceId': 'i-<id>', 'PreviousState': {'Code': 80, 'Name': 'stopped'}}], [..]
```

But in the UI it's not up, not even pending. I've run the code 7 times and its the same thing. To make a test, I tried the opposite: I started the instance using the UI and used the `stop_instances` function and it worked!

The permissions are these:

```
"ec2:StartInstances",
"ec2:StopInstances"
```

What might be happening?

Comment: If you use the awscli on that same EC2 instance to [start](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/start-instances.html) the other, stopped instance, does it work? If not, does awscli work from outside of the EC2 instance?

Comment: HI, @jarmod. No, it didn't work... I even tried give full ec2 access in the permission, but it didn't solve it.

Comment: From outside the EC2 instance it works. I ran the same command on my machine with my own user (not the one that I created to the instance where I'm running Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the instance that I was trying to start have an encrypted EBS volume. Then, it is necessary to give some KMS permissions, I found them here: https://nqbao.medium.com/aws-correct-permission-to-start-an-ec2-instance-with-encrypted-ebs-507933c01511

It is weird that the console don't show an error in this case.

Comment: Good work finding out the root cause. Presume your permissions in the AWS console and awscli (outside of the instance) are different to those of the IAM role associated with the EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks, Jarmod! Yes, my own permissions are admin, whereas the ones that the EC2 was using is limited.

Answer (score 0):

The Python code I am using works fine. It creates an EC2 instance that shows up in the AWS Management Console. Here is output in PyCharm.

[image]

Here is instance in the Console

[image]

Python code is:

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class InstanceWrapper:
    """Encapsulates Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance actions."""

    def __init__(self, ec2_resource, instance=None):
        self.ec2_resource = ec2_resource
        self.instance = instance

    def create(self, image, instance_type, key_pair, security_groups=None):
        try:
            instance_params = {
                'ImageId': image.id, 'InstanceType': instance_type, 'KeyName': key_pair.name
            }
            if security_groups is not None:
                instance_params['SecurityGroupIds'] = [sg.id for sg in security_groups]
            self.instance = self.ec2_resource.create_instances(**instance_params, MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)[0]
            self.instance.wait_until_running()
        except ClientError as err:
            logging.error(
                "Couldn't create instance with image %s, instance type %s, and key %s. "
                "Here's why: %s: %s", image.id, instance_type, key_pair.name,
                err.response['Error']['Code'], err.response['Error']['Message'])
            raise
        else:
            return self.instance

    def display(self, indent=1):
        if self.instance is None:
            logger.info("No instance to display.")
            return

        try:
            self.instance.load()
            ind = '\t' * indent
            print(f"{ind}ID: {self.instance.id}")
            print(f"{ind}Image ID: {self.instance.image_id}")
            print(f"{ind}Instance type: {self.instance.instance_type}")
            print(f"{ind}Key name: {self.instance.key_name}")
            print(f"{ind}VPC ID: {self.instance.vpc_id}")
            print(f"{ind}Public IP: {self.instance.public_ip_address}")
            print(f"{ind}State: {self.instance.state['Name']}")
        except ClientError as err:
            logger.error(
                "Couldn't display your instance. Here's why: %s: %s",
                err.response['Error']['Code'], err.response['Error']['Message'])
            raise

    def terminate(self):
        if self.instance is None:
            logger.info("No instance to terminate.")
            return

        instance_id = self.instance.id
        try:
            self.instance.terminate()
            self.instance.wait_until_terminated()
            self.instance = None
        except ClientError as err:
            logging.error(
                "Couldn't terminate instance %s. Here's why: %s: %s", instance_id,
                err.response['Error']['Code'], err.response['Error']['Message'])
            raise

    def start(self):
        if self.instance is None:
            logger.info("No instance to start.")
            return

        try:
            response = self.instance.start()
            self.instance.wait_until_running()
        except ClientError as err:
            logger.error(
                "Couldn't start instance %s. Here's why: %s: %s", self.instance.id,
                err.response['Error']['Code'], err.response['Error']['Message'])
            raise
        else:
            return response

    def stop(self):
        if self.instance is None:
            logger.info("No instance to stop.")
            return

        try:
            response = self.instance.stop()
            self.instance.wait_until_stopped()
        except ClientError as err:
            logger.error(
                "Couldn't stop instance %s. Here's why: %s: %s", self.instance.id,
                err.response['Error']['Code'], err.response['Error']['Message'])
            raise
        else:
            return response

    def get_images(self, image_ids):
        try:
            images = list(self.ec2_resource.images.filter(ImageIds=image_ids))
        except ClientError as err:
            logger.error(
                "Couldn't get images. Here's why: %s: %s",
                err.response['Error']['Code'], err.response['Error']['Message'])
            raise
        else:
            return images

    def get_instance_types(self, architecture):
        try:
            inst_types = []
            it_paginator = self.ec2_resource.meta.client.get_paginator('describe_instance_types')
            for page in it_paginator.paginate(
                    Filters=[{
                        'Name': 'processor-info.supported-architecture', 'Values': [architecture]},
                        {'Name': 'instance-type', 'Values': ['*.micro', '*.small']}]):
                inst_types += page['InstanceTypes']
        except ClientError as err:
            logger.error(
                "Couldn't get instance types. Here's why: %s: %s",
                err.response['Error']['Code'], err.response['Error']['Message'])
            raise
        else:
            return inst_types


def main11():
    # Replace 'your-image-id', 'your-instance-type', 'your-key-pair-name', and 'your-security-groups'
    # with your actual values
    image_id = 'ami-043326'
    instance_type = 't1.micro'
    key_pair_name = 'scottkeys'
    security_groups = None  # Replace with your actual security groups if needed

    # Create an EC2 resource
    ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')

    # Create an instance of InstanceWrapper
    instance_wrapper = InstanceWrapper(ec2_resource)

    # Create an EC2 instance
    created_instance = instance_wrapper.create(
        image=instance_wrapper.get_images([image_id])[0],
        instance_type=instance_type,
        key_pair=ec2_resource.KeyPair(key_pair_name),
        security_groups=security_groups
    )

    # Display information about the created instance
    instance_wrapper.display()

    # Stop and then start the instance (for demonstration purposes)
    instance_wrapper.stop()
    instance_wrapper.start()

    # Terminate the instance
    instance_wrapper.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main11()
```

Make sure you enter a valid ID value in the above code.

Try that code and you will see the instance in the console. Set a break point after you start it.

Comment: Thanks! Fortunately it wasn't a Python error, but a lack of permissions.